# Scikit-learn Custom Scoring Function

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm currently using the development branch of scikit-learn: 0.15-git.

Trying to initialize a `RidgeClassifierCV` object with a custom scoring function is currently failing with error message `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'scoring'`.

```
model = RidgeClassifierCV(scoring=make_scorer(score_func))
```

According to the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RidgeClassifierCV.html), RidgeClassifier takes a `scoring` parameter. But according to the function signature, the argument is `score_func`. However, passing the output of `sklearn.metrics.maker_scorer` as `score_func` also fails.  Any ideas?

The end goal is to get RidgeClassifierCV working with multiclass (one vs. all) roc auc scores used for the scoring function.

Comment: In the parameter doc they say "scoring", but the function definition only has a "score_func" optional parameter... ?

Comment: Okay, sorry, You mention this already. I clicked on the link at thought I had maybe solved your issue

Comment: No worries -- never hurts to clarify.

Comment: That's a [bug](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/3292).

Comment: @MadisonMay Looks like you will be able to pass scorer objects very soon.

Comment: Yup, just noticed the bug report filed.

Comment: Also, talk about quick turn around time.  1 hour from Stack Overflow question asked to pull request filed.  Not too shabby...

Comment: 1) This is the way the project advances fastest - users discovering issues and reporting them. Please continue like that.
2) There are some extremely efficient people contributing to this project, one of which you just saw in action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`score_func` as opposed to the now standard scikit-learn scoring objects take as arguments `y_true, y_pred`, instead of `estimator, X, y_true`. So if you have written your own scoring function that can work with predictions coming out of the Ridge classifier, then this is the signature you need.

Although `score_func` is deprecated, it seems to be the only option in the current state of the master branch. This will almost surely change with the `0.15` release and scoring objects will be available. The fact that this is documented wrongly is a discrepancy that should also be fixed then.

Comment: Is the custom score function still passed to make_scorer()?  The signature of the current scoring function I'm using is in fact `y_true`, `y_pred`.

Comment: If your scoring function is called e.g. `scoring_function`, then pass it as `score_func=scoring_function` and it should work (and give you a deprecation message)

Comment: Is this still correct? Looks like make_score has taken over the custom scoring but for some reason it doesnt take in y_true and y_pred anymore ?

Comment: all old score functions still exist in `sklearn.metrics` but estimators now take scorer objects which take the estimator as well as `X_test` and `y_test` as inputs. It usually uses the estimator and `X_test` to create `y_pred` and then a metric to compare to `y_test`, but sometimes it does something different. Does this help?